# Criteria for $LU$ decomposition

Tags: matrices

1.) Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n.$ Define $V_k(A)$ as $k\times k$ upper left submatrix $A.$ Suppose $A$ has $LU$ decomposition, is it true that $V_k(A)$ is invertible for all $k \ ?$

2.) I read that if $A$ is invertible, then it has $LU$ decomposition if and only if all its leading principal minors are non-zero.  May I know what is a principal leading minor? Examples will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: 2.) These are precisely the $V_k\left(A\right)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951461/lu-factorization-of-a-nonsingular-matrix-exists-if-and-only-if-all-leading-princ/2955663#2955663 for proofs of the result you are referring to.

Comment: 1.) No, because $A$ may be the zero matrix. In general (i.e., if you don't require $A$ to be invertible), I don't know of a good criterion for when $A$ has an LU decomposition.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thank you. If we require $A$ be to non-zero as well,  hence, if $A$ had LU decomposition, does it mean $V_k(A)$ is invertible for all $k?$

Comment: Nope, you need $A$ to be invertible for that conclusion. There is a lot of room between fully zero and invertible.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thank you for the advice. Is there an example of a square matrix $A$ that has $LU$ decomposition but $V_k(A)$ is not invertible for some $k ?$

Comment: You can easily come up with one: Just multiply a lower-triangular and an upper-triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are not all nonzero.